# I'm not getting the FCM with buttons when app in background...?

Tags: background, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not getting the FCM with buttons when app in background, I'm getting FCM in background but without buttons, in foreground it's working.

This is the code I use:

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
          .setContentTitle(title)
      //    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
          .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
          .setContentText(body)
          .setAutoCancel(true)
          .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
  //        .setVibrate(new long[]{500})
          .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
          .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
          .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Accept", pendingIntent)
          .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Reject", pendingIntent)
          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  NotificationManager manager =
          (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
              "Default channel",
              NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
      channel.setShowBadge(true);
      channel.setLockscreenVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
  //    channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{500});
 //     channel.enableVibration(true);
      manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
//      manager.notify(0,builder.build());
  }
  manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Comment: Did u override onMessageReceived if it is yes then expend ur notifications your button will be shown because some time action button collapse with notifications.

Comment: there was nothing to extend... set the priority to high  but its wasnt working....